# How to send monero from my cold storage?

Tags: cold-storage, wallet-recovery

I have a Monero paper wallet and want to send money from it to another address. What's the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The currently easiest way is to restore your seed using the CLI wallet, spend what you want to spend and immediately send the remainder to a **newly created** cold storage. See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/what-are-the-best-practices-to-move-coins-out-of-cold-storage) for some more considerations.

To make syncing the wallet faster, you can start the CLI wallet with `--restore-deterministic-wallet --restore-height <h>` arguments, where `<h>` is the block height from which it will start the refresh. If you know the approx date when you sent the first funds to it, use a [block explorer](http://chainradar.com/xmr/blocks) to find the No. of block that was a bit before the time you sent the funds and use that number as the starting height. While this will speed up the initial sync significantly, be absolutely sure you use a block height from before your funds came, otherwise you won't see them in that wallet.

PS easier methods are soon to be avaliable. The Trezor firmware is in testing phase, and the new point release will provide option for offline signing, meaning you'll be able to spend from cold storage without ever exposing it to an online computer.